# Retrieving next available AutoNumber

Tags: java, sql, ms-access, sequences

I am busy with a school project where I query a database based on a server from a client. One of the requirements is to retrieve the next available `AutoNumber` from the database.

What would the SQL query be to retrieve the next available `Autonumber`? Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the flavor of the RDBMS. MariaDB (MySQL) have LAST_INSERT_ID() function which gives you the last value of an AUTO_INCREMENT field.

Databases that support sequences (say Ingres) allow you to get next value with something like:

```
SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR some_sequence;
```

or

```
SELECT some_sequence.NEXTVAL;
```

Comment: Thanks, I however forgot to mention...the database in MSAccess. Will a similar query still work?

Comment: I never used M$ Access, but I found out it has: `IDENT_CURRENT('table_name')` - This function apparently gives you the last ID of the last inserted record in the table...

Answer (score 2):

The next autonumber is not the same as the last autonumber +1. If records have been deleted, the next possible autonumber could be considerably higher that the last number. It is also possible to get negative autonumbers with MS Access. As [Allen Browne](http://www.allenbrowne.com/ser-40.html) shows, you can use ADOX to get the seed property of the autonumber column, which is the next autonumber.

Answer (score 1):

If it's Oracle, then run the below query using JDBC

```
SELECT YOUR_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL
```

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to insert a record, then get generated keys, and then rollback the transaction.
It works on all databases with transaction and auto-number support.

Comment: The problem is that if you are in a multi-user environment there is no guarantee that someone else will not insert a record between when you perform this operation and when you actually insert the record.

Comment: There is no problem, you want a unique number, and you get it.

Comment: There is a problem. You roll back the transaction. Your number is now the property of someone else. I do not really see the value of getting the next autonumber any way, because no matter how you get it, it could be gone by the time you need it.