# Access 2007 Autonumber Incrementing Sporadically

Tags: ms-access-2007, autonumber

I was hoping someone would be able to help with why one of my Access 2007 databases seems to be rather randomly assigning an autonumber as an ID.

I understand that it's a unique number assigned automatically by access.

My question is why has access jumped from 4 to over 50,000,000 when no data has been inserted since record 4 as below?

[image: Example]

Comment: Are there any programmatic updates of the table? Have you compacted & repaired recently? Could anyone have tampered with the Autonumber setting? You might like to read http://allenbrowne.com/ser-40.html

Comment: @Remou Since creating this database, no amendments have been made to this table. I've tried compacting and repairing to no avail. No-one else has access to the database. That was an interesting read thanks and seems to describe the problem but the function provided to fix is only for negative / duplicate values.

Comment: You can reset the value of the seed, but unless you find the problem the number may jump again. There is a general rule that you should not worry about the value of an autonumber, it is only there to be unique. Some more reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554857/retrieving-next-available-autonumber/9558437#9558437 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4416619/how-to-start-counting-from-1-after-erase-table-in-access/4419687#4419687

Comment: It is possible that deleting the row you do not like and then compacting and repairing will work for you.